# Who is this guy holding a gold sword who appeared after I returned home via a portal?

Tags: minetest, mineclone-5

I'm playing [Mineclone 5](https://content.minetest.net/packages/kay27/mineclone5/) (a Minecraft clone) single player via Minetest.

> [image: screenshot of a character who appeared after I returned home via a portal; he holds a gold sword, and in the background is the portal inside a house]

The second time I returned via the portal, this guy appeared (the first time he didn't appear).  He doesn't attack me.  If I right click on him, nothing happens.

**Question**: Who is this guy holding a gold sword who appeared after I returned home via a portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a zombified piglin [MineClone5 source: image of texture](https://github.com/kay27/MineClone5/blob/mineclone5/mods/ENTITIES/extra_mobs/textures/extra_mobs_zombified_piglin.png)
but the texture looks different, maybe your clone uses a different texture or I didn't find the same source code base.

In vanilla Minecraft only zombified piglins could appear in the overworld through the portal. It may be the same implementation as in yours (with similar item assignment rng)

Comment: “zombies, zombified piglins and skeletons could appear in the overworld through the portal” Only zombified piglins can do so.  Zombies and skeletons spawn as part of the general hostile mob spawning mechanism and have nothing to do with nether portals.

Comment: @L.F. Thanks, ive edited my answer, you could have aswell I think.

Comment: @CodeAsm While L. F. could edit your answer, it is better to let answerer (in this case, you) to know the correct information by commenting. Most of the time edit by another person is only done for fixing spelling, grammar, format and such, like I did to your answer.